# Getting "ApiAccessDeniedError" while developing the basic extension on Shopify

Tags: shopify-storefront-api, shopify-app-extension

I have been facing the error "ApiAccessDeniedError" while developing my very first extension on Shopify. I am following their [tutorial](https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/checkout/product-offers/pre-purchase/getting-started) on Building the pre-purchase product offers extension.

I have updated my `shopify.app.toml` file with the code they provided but its not working.

My shopify.app.toml file looks like this:

```
[capabilities]
api_access = true
```

The error:

> ApiAccessDeniedError: Extension is not allowed to use the Storefront
> API; permission to use the Storefront API must be specified under
> [capabilities] with:"api_access = true;